# How to address MSDN's Caution: Associate BeginTransaction before Readers are Open

Tags: sql, sql-server

I noticed a caution in the `BeginTransaction` documentation located here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86773566.aspx

> When your query returns a large amount of data and calls
>   BeginTransaction, a SqlException is thrown because SQL Server does not
>   allow parallel transactions when using MARS. To avoid this problem,
>   always associate a transaction with the command, the connection, or
>   both before any readers are open.

Is this suggestion that I change this:

```
sqlConn.Open();

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction trans = sqlConn.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted); 
sqlCmd.Transaction = trans;

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter adapt = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
adapt.Fill(dt);
```

To this, which is not what I normally see in examples, with the `BeginTransaction` command BEFORE the `Open` command...

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction trans = sqlConn.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted); 
sqlCmd.Transaction = trans;

sqlConn.Open();

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter adapt = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
adapt.Fill(dt);
```

Otherwise, can anyone give an example of what this caution is saying to avoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter code will not execute because you cannot start a transaction before having an open connection. The first example is correct. What MSDN is saying here is that once you have started executing a command (and not finished reading results), you cannot open a transaction. You have to open the transaction before your first command (or between commands).

I consider it best practice to always operate under an explicit transaction because there is a bug/feature in the ADO.NET connection pooling that leaks isolation levels across pooled connections.

Comment: I'm looking at this documentation because we are running into a very random bug in which the datatable is very sporatically not being populated (no data is returned?).  I'm wondering if MARS should be set to FALSE given the message above.  Or is there something that I should do to make transactions explicit?

Comment: Are you *using* MARS or just have it turned on? If you're not using it, turn it off. It brings some usage rules with it and it causes 14 bytes to be added to every rows that is being touched under MARS (if not already present).

Comment: Are you using the same connection concurrently? That's a no-go, too.

Comment: MultipleActiveResultSets=true in the connection string.  You think it might be the cause of errors?